# @font-face Crashing IE & Firefox

Tags: jquery, css, font-face

I'm using `@font-face` on my website as well as Typekit. The reason i'm using both is because i use `@font-face` for icons and Typekit doesnt provide any fonts of this nature. I created my Icon Font with the awesome tool that is [IcoMoon App](http://icomoon.io/app/%22IcoMoon).

After spending several hours sifting through my `stylesheets` and `js` files i learned that when `@font-face` was present in my `stylesheet` then on some Windows7 Machines using Firefox or Internet Exporer (latest versions) the browser will hang for a while or in some cases crash and then restart. After this happens the website works just fine.

Anyone have any ideas on how i can prevent this from happening?

Below is my `@font-face` code from my stylesheet, and [here](http://devsite87.clickdealer.co.uk) is the website i'm using it on.

**Thank you in advance!!**

```
@font-face {
font-family: "icomoon";
src:url("/css/fonts/icomoon.eot");
src:url("/css/fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/css/fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon") format("svg"),
    url("/css/fonts/icomoon.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/css/fonts/icomoon.ttf") format("truetype");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

Note: *I'm perfectly open to suggestions and fixes with Jquery if there are any!*

Comment: Have you tried a different font? I use @font-face and have no issues with IE/FF at all. Perhaps however the font was made is what the problem is, not @font-face?

Comment: No i haven't thought of that i'll try now and let you know the result

Comment: I suggest you use fontsquirel or http://www.font2web.com/ services to create propper font-face syntax and files. Maybe that also helps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem appears to be directly with the IcoMoon App. After creating my Icon Font with IcoMoon i uploaded the `ttf` file with Font Squirrel's own generator and low and behold no browsers crashed and page load speed was 10x faster!

Answer (score 0):

I would be very surprised if CSS is crashing your browser. Probably the icon font you created is corrupted.

Comment: i've tested with another font from font-squirrel and there was no issues with load time speeds etc. The problem appears to be only with the font file that Firefox uses (WOFF) ?